# Accessing Current Record in Lightning Component

Tags: salesforce

To access data within the a Lightning view, is it necessary to write client controller code that polls a server-side controller?

This makes sense based on my experience in other languages. But I was hoping / thought I read that somehow the immediate object's data - ex. on a record page - would be injected into the view. It just feels like this is a lot of boiler plate code to write on a platform that's supposed to expedite development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per people on the SF stackexchange site, yes, one has to write a bunch of boiler plate code (two controllers) to get data for the current record.